# hide back button in google forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

how can I hide back button in google form ?
does it is possible using google app script?

I am trying to hide the hide button in my google form when making exams , I try write  google app script
but it does not working

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It's not possible using Google Apps Script. You might have to create a web browser extension or make use of bookmarklet (not really an option for academic / professional exams ) . If you need further help please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].